# Attempt to reopen an already-closed object sqlitedatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a databaseHandler. I need to count the rows in table. App crashes by this error: `android attempt to reopen an already-closed object sqlitedatabase`.
I simply use this code in activity:

```
db.getContactsCount();
```

But app crashes. Furthemore I want to reset the tables (delete table rows). I added the method  below:

```
public void deleteTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("contacts", null, null);
    }
```

It works good but I can't use this one:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}
```

This is the databasehandler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**
 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */

// Adding new contact
void addContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single contact
Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
    // return contact
    return contact;
}

// Getting All Contacts
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
            // Adding contact to list
            contactList.add(contact);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return contact list
    return contactList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
}

// Deleting single contact
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    db.close();
}


// Getting contacts Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}

public void Upgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Deleting single contact
    public void deleteTable() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete("contacts", null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply open it by using the line something called myDb.open(). Then do your work.

Comment: Hola. `myDb.open()` will Upgrade the database? deleting table rows ,...?

Answer (score 26):

It happens because of the:

`db.close();`

in the methods:

`void addContact(Contact contact)`

`public void deleteContact(Contact contact)`

You should not close the connection to the underlying database unless you *really* do not intend to work with it anymore. 
Use `SQLiteOpenHelper:close`, when you've finished your work.

Moreover, calls to `getReadableDatabase()` and `getWriteableDatabase()` return the same database object 99% of a time, and they **do not** reinitialize database connection closed manually by you.

Don't get fooled by these method names.

Comment: getReadableDatabase() or getWriteableDatabase() not work for me.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to suggest you that, dont close database object before complete your database work.

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
db = this.getWritableDatabase();

or

db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```

Above both method give us database object using helper class and using this object we can do different actions on database. But in your scenario, I think so you closed database object before complete database operation. So closed after done all operation by using

```
db.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

The onUpgrade is when you made changes to your database (ie adding tables) so there is now a new version of your database. Your:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

is now

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

Because the database version is now higher newer version the OnUpgrade() method is called and updates the database.

Answer (score 3):

I should have defined `int count = cursor.getCount();` before closing the database. It seems `return cursor.getCount();` after closing the database is a useless effort.
At last removing `db.close();` at the end of delete and remove methods was necessary.
Adding this code instead in handler instead helped alot:

```
public void closeDB() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null && db.isOpen())
        db.close();
}
```

Manipulating `close` function inside activity at the end of database usage was better. Thanks to @Drew.
I still can't understand the usage of `onUpgrade` inside handler ???

Answer (score 3):

it basically happens because of cursor.close();
since you are closing the cursor object before you are returning its count.