# java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hello I am trying to query data from local database in android. 
There are two models Category and News in 1:m relationship. I want to search for list of news according to their categoryID. But when I do it I am getting following exception.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.infiniteloop.newsmobile/com.infiniteloop.newsmobile.NewsList}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.infiniteloop.newsmobile/databases/NEWS_DB
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.infiniteloop.newsmobile/databases/NEWS_DB
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1312)
                                                                           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                                           at com.infiniteloop.newsmobile.db.NewsDBAdapter.getNewsByCategory(NewsDBAdapter.java:105)
                                                                           at com.infiniteloop.newsmobile.data_models.NewsManager.getNewsByCategory(NewsManager.java:100)
```

This is my query in NewsDBAdapter.

```
public Cursor getNewsByCategory(int Cat_ID){

    Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NEWS + " WHERE " +
            NEWS_CATEGORY_ID + " = " + Cat_ID + ";", null);

    return c;
}
```

I am calling this method in another class

```
public List<News> getNewsByCategory(int categoryID){

    List<News> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor c = null;
    try {

        if(!adapter.isDBOpen()){
            adapter.openDB();
        }
        c = adapter.getNewsByCategory(categoryID);
        Log.i(TAG, "getNewsByCategory: " +  c);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int News_ID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(NEWS_ID));
                String News_TITLE = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NEWS_TITLE));
                String News_Content = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NEWS_CONTENT));
                String News_Date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NEWS_DATE));
                String News_IMGURL = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(NEWS_IMGURL));
                int News_Category_ID = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(NEWS_CATEGORY_ID));
                News news = new News(News_ID, News_TITLE, News_Content, News_Date, News_IMGURL, News_Category_ID);
                newsList.add(news);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return newsList;
    }finally {
        if (c!=null){
            c.close();
        }
        if(adapter.isDBOpen()){
            adapter.closeDB();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to this post: [Attempt to reopen an already-closed object sqlitedatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166323/attempt-to-reopen-an-already-closed-object-sqlitedatabase)

But you did not use the readable instance of the database.
Try the below code:

```
public Cursor getNewsByCategory(int Cat_ID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = adapter.getReadableDatabase(); // You need to call
    Cursor  c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NEWS + " WHERE " +
            NEWS_CATEGORY_ID + " = " + Cat_ID + ";", null);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but no change. IMHO the problem is DB is already closed somewhere before reaching this method. Can't figure out where

Comment: @IbrokhimjonSaydakhmatov what the datatype of `adapter`?

Comment: It is NewsDBAdapter object which includes NewsHelper class (extends SQLiteOpeHelper). Inside the class I wrote CRUD.

Comment: @IbrokhimjonSaydakhmatov I've edited my answer, it seems I found a similar issue. But in this case, you forgot to use the readable database instance.

Comment: Still no luck((

Comment: @IbrokhimjonSaydakhmatov Did you try removing the `openDb` and `closeDb`?

Comment: Yes it worked when I removed closeDB() inside each crud functions

Comment: @IbrokhimjonSaydakhmatov As I suspected. I think you need to refactor your code regarding opening and closing your db. The link I provided above is related to your problem.