# How to fix java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm currently working on my A Level Computer Science controlled assessment, making a Scout Manager App in Android Studio, using Java and XML - none of which I have used before.  I'm now working on a n event creator.

I'm trying to create a record, which will show which transport has been selected for which event, however I have run into a problem - the LogCat is giving me the following error:

```
04-02 15:25:42.663 18482-18482/com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype, PID: 18482
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:390)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:385)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5310) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype/databases/ScoutManager.db
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1158)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
        at com.example.samogonovsky.scoutmanager.databaseHandler.getRandomTransport(databaseHandler.java:649)
        at com.example.samogonovsky.scoutmanager.frmCreateEvent2.saveAndExit(frmCreateEvent2.java:528)
```

However, I have not closed the cursor in either of these two places.

Here is the code in the "databaseHandler" class:

```
//Select a random mode of transport
    public Cursor getRandomTransport()
    {
        Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_TRANSPORT, null, null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()limit 1");
        if (cursor!=null&&cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        else
        {
            cursor=null;
        }
        return cursor;
    }
```

And here is the code in the "frmAddEvent2" class:

```
double TotalTransportCost;
        if (providingtransport==true)
        {
            int peopletotransport=noOfPeople;
            TotalTransportCost = 0;
            do
            {

                int eventtransportid=createEventTransportId();

                Cursor ModeOfTransport = DatabaseHandler.getRandomTransport();

                if (ModeOfTransport.moveToFirst()) {

                    int transportid=ModeOfTransport.getInt(ModeOfTransport.getColumnIndex(
                            DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_TRID));

                    double PriceForHiring = ModeOfTransport.getDouble(ModeOfTransport.getColumnIndex(
                            DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_HCOST));

                    double PricePerMile = ModeOfTransport.getDouble(ModeOfTransport.getColumnIndex(
                            DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_MCOST));

                    int NoOfSeats = ModeOfTransport.getInt(ModeOfTransport.getColumnIndex(
                            DatabaseHandler.COLUMN_SEATNO));

                    double ModeCost = ((PricePerMile*distancefrombase)+PriceForHiring);

                    eventTransportDetails eventtransport = new eventTransportDetails(eventtransportid,
                            id, transportid);

                    DatabaseHandler.createEventTransport(eventtransport);

                    BigDecimal bigdecimalmodecost=new BigDecimal(ModeCost);
                    BigDecimal bigdecimalpropermodecost=((bigdecimalmodecost.setScale(2,bigdecimalmodecost.ROUND_DOWN)));
                    double propermodecost=bigdecimalpropermodecost.doubleValue();
                    TotalTransportCost = TotalTransportCost + propermodecost;
                    peopletotransport = (peopletotransport-NoOfSeats);
                    ModeOfTransport.close();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            context,
                            "Error - you have not added any lunches, therefore food " +
                                    "cannot be added.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
                    return;
                }
            }
            while (peopletotransport>0);
        }
        else
        {
            TotalTransportCost=0;
        }
```

I was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction?

Also, feel free to suggest any improvements to my question - as stated, a lot of this is new to me, so I may have left out some pretty important material.

Comment: `Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_TRANSPORT`... Show us the code where you acquire `db` and/or make sure you don't `close()` it prior to use.

Comment: FYI. From the stack trace you posted, this is your problem: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/data/com.example.atomi.scoutmanagerprototype/databases/ScoutManager.db` and this is the line of your code where the problem is occurring: `at com.example.samogonovsky.scoutmanager.databaseHandler.getRandomTransport(databaseHandler.java:649)` Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10600670/sqlitedatabase-query-method) _Stack Overflow_ question may be of help - assuming you haven't already seen it.

Comment: Alright, cheers guys - I'll take a look and I'll update you.

Comment: You're closing the cursor while you're still querying it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt to reopen an already-closed object sqlitedatabase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166323/attempt-to-reopen-an-already-closed-object-sqlitedatabase)

Comment: I think you may be right Zoe - should I delete this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so as it turns out, I put "db.close();" after a few of the functions in databaseHandler - by removing all of these, I fixed the problem.  If you think this question would be better off not on the site, let me know and I'll delete it.  Thanks though to all who commented.