# Android Room Database Migrate closed Database

Tags: android, android-room

Room Database Migrate method

```
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE menuItems ADD COLUMN cnt INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL");
    }
```

database is throwing an error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:
```

I have not used database close method anywhere in the method.
I am not able to alter database table.
How to get rid of above exception.

I tried to open database in migrate method.

Comment: The object that has been closed can't be reopened is an SQLiteDatabase rather than a SupportSQLiteDatabase. I would suggest that you edit your question to include more of the stack trace and also the code to which it points to.

Comment: i think this is help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166323/attempt-to-reopen-an-already-closed-object-sqlitedatabase

Answer (score 0):

we migrated to room latest version and used automigrationspec to solve this issue